# yii2 autocompelete not work for me

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i have table that have developer_id, name, family .etc columns 
i want to show suggest name in input in view i did something like this but this give me a input whitout any suggestion and autocompelte
why?

```
$data = Developers::find()
    ->select(['name as value', 'name as  label','developer_id as id'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

    echo AutoComplete::widget([
        'name' => 'dname',
        'id' => 'ddd',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'source' => $data,
            'autoFill'=>true,
            'minLength'=>'1',
            'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
            $('#aa').val(ui.item.id);
        }")],
    ]);
     ?>
<input id="aa"  value="" type="hidden">
```

Comment: @scaisEdge any idea

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code in one of my views. I just changed your model so I am using one of my models (tables). Your code works perfectly in my view. So I think you should check if the problem is one of these:

1. You are not correctly importing one of these:

   use backend\models\Developers;

   use yii\jui\AutoComplete;

   use yii\web\JsExpression;
2. Your table Developers is empty
3. In the part of your code that says:

   ->select(['name as value', 'name as  label','developer_id as id'])

   Are you sure your table developer has the columns name and developer_id?

Comment: use app\models\Developers;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\jui\AutoComplete;
use yii\web\JsExpression;
use yii\web\View;

are imported well  and if i print_r() $data i can see values as well .... its really Weird